# Dealing with a generated PDF from LaTeX in Git

Tags: git, pdf, latex

(small disclaimer: I just started using Git so this might have a very easy solution that I am unaware off, sorry for that.)

I wanted to use Git to do a version control of my LaTeX report (using GitLab).

The source code is added to the master branch but I would also like to have the PDF that is generated from the source code to be in the branch. This way I can view the PDF on the website when I am using my phone or other computer for example.

Question 1.

TLDR: How to store an "only latest version" of a file using Git?

I don't need version control on this PDF as the old versions can all be generated using an older version of the source code if I need them.

I just need Git to store the latest version of my PDF and that when I use

```
git add *
git commit -m ''
git push
```

that it checks if the PDF has changed or not and if it has that it replaced the older version on the server with my newer version.

Question 2.

This is just my first thought of dealing with this problem but what are other alternatives to deal with source code generated files that you want to store in the repository using Git?

Comment: The generated PDF is a build artifact, and build artifacts do not belong in version control.

Comment: Does GitLab have something like Github's GH pages?

Comment: @Nick I don't know what GH pages are but what I do know is that when I click on the PDF in my repository on the GitLab website it opens a link that looks like this: https://gitlab.com/username/Report/blob/master/Report.pdf, which I can use to view my PDF on my phone.